# How do I stop the event bubbles in dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, event-bubbling

```
Here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FAehp/3/
```

I want to add a even listener to the parent view. But it bubbled by the drop down menus.

Any one face this issue? or am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/FAehp/7/

This might help but creating exceptions to the rule might be annoying. You can use `.is()` or `.closest()` to create a general rule if you decide to add anything more (eg. http://jsfiddle.net/FAehp/14/)

You could also use `.is()` to make sure it's actually the parent div: http://jsfiddle.net/FAehp/11/ but if you add any child elements to it then it won't work.